# Invoking Clojure from Java throws NullPointerException that does not contain stacktrace

Tags: java, exception, tomcat, clojure

This specific question is related to the missing stacktrace for the NullPointerException raised.

So I have a Clojure file, which gets compiled by my Java web app using the following:

```
Compiler.loadFile("/tmp/test.clj");
Var cljFunc = RT.var("abc", "foo");
cljFunc.invoke(12);
```

However, I'm getting a NullPointerException at the line of `cljfunc.invoke(12)`. I'm expecting it to show (in the stacktrace) the line number .clj file that the exception occurred. But the stacktrace is null. I added `-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow` in the Tomcat launch command to turn off the JVM optimization. But it did not help.

Comment: Would you post some source code and how you are building it?

Comment: Are you maybe using some kind of logger (settings or level) that filters out the exceptions?

Comment: I'll try to post the src later. No, it has nothing to do with logging. The stacktrace is not even showing up in the debugger.

Comment: Your file is in `/tmp/test.clj` so I guess the namespace should be `tmp.test` and not `abc`

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that `cljFunc` is null when you call `invoke` on it.